# Does NestJS comes with security practices already?

Tags: node.js, security, nestjs, typeorm, nodejs-server

Does NestJS handles some security practices out of the box?. If not, what recommendations can you share to secure a NestJS application besides helmet? I see in the NestJS middleware docs an example using the helmet dependency.

When using TypeORM, SQL injection is covered?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nest doesn't bring anything else than an actual HTTP provider used underneath (express/fastify). In order to stay flexible, we didn't decide to force anyone to use particular tools. Instead, you can choose whatever you want.

In terms of TypeORM, as far as I know, the SQL injection is prevented.

Answer (score 2):

**NestJS** follows mostly the same security rules as the [**Node.js**](https://www.educative.io/blog/secure-nodejs-apps-best-practices) server and [**Express**](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-security.html).

**NestJS has an dedicated security section** in its documentation that addresses these topics:

- [Authentication](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication)
- [Authorization](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authorization)
- [Encryption and Hashing](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/encryption-and-hashing)
- [Helmet](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/helmet)
- [CORS](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/cors)
- [CSRF Protection](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/csrf)
- [Rate limiting](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/rate-limiting)

**When it comes to protecting against SQL Injection, I think sanitize input and parameterized statements are the most important.**

Overall, however, it is most important that **programmers do not cause security holes through code and architecture, but follow with good security practices and as administrators to expose to production hardened services with the least privileges**. It is important to educate ourselves in this area all the time.